# How to get a specific value from JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am running a function which returns json data:

```
const stocks = await response.json();
let stocksData = stocks.values;
```

If I print out the result gives a result as:

```
0 :  {datetime: '2023-01-18', open: '1.07940', high: '1.08870', low: '1.07670', close: '1.07970'}
1 :  {datetime: '2023-01-19', open: '1.07945', high: '1.08365', low: '1.07820', close: '1.08300'} 
2 :  {datetime: '2023-01-20', open: '1.08300', high: '1.08585', low: '1.08020', close: '1.08530'} 
3 :  {datetime: '2023-01-23', open: '1.08595', high: '1.09270', low: '1.0
```

I am trying to get values as: ***open, high, low, close*** with below line of code:

```
var open = stocksData["open"];
```

and print:

`console.log("Open: " + open);`

I get result:

> Open: undefined

I thought its because **stocksData** is an object and tried to change it to a string and try to access the value again as follows:

```
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stocksData)); 
var high = b["high"];
console.log("High: " + high);
```

I still get:

> High: undefined

And there where I am stuck now, where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: You can't completely ignore the fact you have **multiple** objects (0, 1, 2, 3) and try to treat `stocks.values` as a *single* object.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that `stocks.values` is an array, so you can use something like

```
var open = stocksData[0]["open"];
```

Or, you can loop through the array with an `for`-loop of some kind

Edit:

```
for (entry of stocksData) {
  console.log('Open: ' + entry.open)
  console.log('High: ' + entry.high)
  console.log('Low: ' + entry.low)
  console.log('Close: ' + entry.close)
}
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for all documentation regarding arrays and looping

Comment: how do I loop it

Comment: I added an example